# Authentication Integration with Google

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a web application which works on windows active directory.Since it is deployed on Local IIS, windows authentications works fine. Now I am planning to move the authentication part of the application to cloud so that I can use AD users of multiple domain using OpenID connect(oAuth2). I am able to set OpenID connect to login  using external user (using GoogleAuthentication)  using email Id. 
My query is

1.Can I create my AD User to https://console.cloud.google.com ?

2. Can I login my site using
   that User ?
3. Can cloud.google authenticate the used from my Active
   Directory?

If anyone could guide me with some links that would be great.